# Django admin breadcrumb for app

Tags: django, url, admin, breadcrumbs

Hardcoding a breadcrumb in a non-Admin template - with a model looks like this:

```
    <a href="{% url 'admin:myapp_mymodel_changelist' %}">{% trans 'MyModels' %}</a>
```

Easy enough. My problem is in making a breadcrumb for just the app. I would expect something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:app_list_myapp' %}">{% trans 'MyApp' %}</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:app_list_myapp_index' %}">{% trans 'MyApp' %}</a>
```

Or

```
 <a href="{% url 'admin:myapp_index' %}">{% trans 'MyApp' %}</a>
```

None of which work. As well as quite a few other things I've tried. Can someone put me out of my misery? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The url name is actually just `app_list`, the application name is passed as an argument:

```
{% url 'admin:app_list' 'myapp' %}
```

See [the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L247) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are based on paths to views, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url